# Restore deleted items by delete day

Tags: data-recovery, undelete, photorec

Is there any way to use photorec or another program to restore items deleted only within the last 2 days or so?

Answer (score 0):

Photorec can try to recover whatever is still there. The files may be only partial files, old files, or newly deleted files.

You can, however, specify the file type and I believe you might be able to specify file sizes as well but I've never used such an option.

there is more info on the photorec wiki [http://www.cgsecurity.org](http://www.cgsecurity.org/wiki/PhotoRec)

Answer (score 0):

You have to try some Data Recovery tools which may help you to restore some of your old data.

[From R-tools Technology:](http://download.cnet.com/windows/R-tools%20Technology/3260-20_4-80773-1.html)

> R-Linux is a free data recovery and undelete utility for Ext2FS/3FS
>   (Linux) file systems. File recovery after power failure, system crash,
>   virus infection, or partition reformation, even for the different file
>   system. Unformat and unerase tool. The utility creates image files an
>   entire disk, partition or its part. Such drive image can be processed
>   like regular drive

You can [download 64 bit verion from here](http://download.cnet.com/R-Linux-Free-Recovery/3000-2248_4-10075543.html).

To install

```
sudo dpkg -i rli_en*.deb
```

Once you install you can make a recovery and choose data according to modification day, so you can choose last 2days only.

Comment: But that's for Windows, not ubuntu.

Comment: NO this is Linux version. please don't just give feedback unless you check before

Comment: The link you gave me contains rli_en_4.exe.

Comment: I tried and found the .deb file, installed it, and got the following error:
/usr/local/R-Linux/bin/R-Linux: error while loading shared libraries: librlin_linux_r.so: cannot open shared object file: No such file or directory